# Is there a less hack-y way to prevent my on('click') from firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, zurb-foundation

I have an element `.trigger` that appears at the top and bottom of my page. It is the child element of `.center` which also appears twice. My code is simple:

```
$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '.trigger', function() {
    alert('success');
});
```

This is messy to me and seems like a hack. but, if I use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function() {
    alert('success');
});
```

It fires twice on click, and I have no idea why? Can anyone explain why this happens, and how to prevent it from happening? If I do:

```
$('.center').on('click', '.trigger', function() {
    alert('success');
});
```

Then it only fires on the second instance of `.trigger` (although it will only fire once, as I expect it to).

Can anyone explain the odd behavior of these three cases, and offer a solution?

**HTML:**

```
// some html
<div class="center">
    <div class="trigger">blah</div>
</div>
// lots of more html
<div class="center">
    <div class="trigger">blah</div>
</div>
// some html
```

**Edit**

The first block of `.trigger` is essentially AJAX'd in using a tool in Foundation called `data-interchange`  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html

Comment: I don't understand the problem, its only firing once for me? http://jsfiddle.net/ygkcpwo3/ you probably have a mistake in your code somewhere and its binding twice. Can you change the class to something else and just change this one binding occurence and add a console.log above it to make sure its not firing the bind twice.

Comment: @A.Wolff this doesn't solve the problem, best approach is to write clean code that isn't binding it twice.

Comment: Or you are loading the same script twice, such as in an ajax call

Comment: @SimonStaton Hmm interesting. I just view sourced on my page and realized that I'm using a Foundation framework tool `data-interchange` which loads content based on user resolution. If one of these portions of my code (the top half) is AJAX'd in, will that affect the functionality? Also if I view source, the first block isn't in the HTML code (just the `data-interchange code that decides which PHP file to load is).

Comment: @HC_ can you add an alert above the bind first to make sure you are not calling the script twice? If this is not the case you have two different bindings in your code.

Comment: @SimonStaton Wow... the alert did indeed trigger twice when placed right above the function definition. This is very odd to me because that's the first thing I checked for and couldn't find how on earth the script could be included twice... I will have to look closer but it feels like I'm not missing anything, but evidently I am. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonStaton Found it!! I had a script that I need to rewrite... it would parse the entire document for `__LANG__` then replace it with something like `eng` to allow for easy customization of links on my end... but it replaced the entire `body` so I guess it duplicated the binding. Thanks a ton for your help.. now to figure out how to solve essentially a page-wide regex without replacing the body. If you'd like to submit your comments as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: No problem, and I wouldn't recommend performing a regex on the entire DOM source. Instead create some kind of node binding to the elements that need this replacing.

Comment: @SimonStaton Could you offer a starting point for that approach? I am essentially attempting to parse all `a href=__LANG__/blah.php` on any page the user is on, and replace `__LANG__` with a string stored in a global javascript variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier this week I searched for a method to regex through the entire `DOM` and replace all occurrences of the string `__LANG__` with the current selected language (ex: `eng`) (for linking purposes).

The code was:

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/_LANG_/g,lang);
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Which replaces the body, but seems to duplicate all my `script`'s as well. If you search on SE for ways to `str_replace` all instances of a string with javascript, the above  code snippet comes up a lot in results, however **I would not recommend  using it as replacing the entire `DOM` seems to be a bad idea.**

After I removed that code, my code stopped firing twice.